# primefaces empty selectItemGroup using filter

Tags: primefaces, filter, selectonemenu

I'm using primefaces. Problem is with SelectOneMenu. Does anyone know if I can, when using filter in SelectOneMenu, remove SelectItemGroups which become empty?